# How to read an email attachment (after I got the GUID with SO_ATTACHMENT_READ)?

Tags: email, abap

I'm trying to get the in memory representation of a file, that is attached to a mail.

I have the ID of the mail, and the ID of the attachment (i worked these out from table SOOD) and transaction SOST.

```
DATA: gs_doc        TYPE soodk,
      gs_attachment TYPE soodk,
      objcont TYPE soli OCCURS 0,
      objhead TYPE soli OCCURS 0.

gs_doc-objtp = 'RAW'.
gs_doc-objyr = '38'.
gs_doc-objno = '000000000465'.

gs_attachment-objtp = 'EXT'.
gs_attachment-objyr = '38'.
gs_attachment-objno = '000000000282'..

*    i_oid        = 'E2ED5468C94941F198A300155D005612'
CALL FUNCTION 'SO_ATTACHMENT_READ'
  EXPORTING
*   FILTER                           =
    object_id                        = gs_doc
   attach_id                        = gs_attachment
*   OWNER                            =
*   FORWARDER                        =
* IMPORTING
*   OBJECT_HD_DISPLAY                =
*   OBJECT_RC_DISPLAY                =
*   OBJECT_FL_DISPLAY                =
 TABLES
   objcont                          = objcont
   objhead                          = objhead
 EXCEPTIONS
   active_user_not_exist            = 1
   object_not_exist                 = 2
   operation_no_authorization       = 3
   owner_not_exist                  = 4
   parameter_error                  = 5
   substitute_not_active            = 6
   substitute_not_defined           = 7
   x_error                          = 8
   communication_failure            = 9
   system_failure                   = 10
   OTHERS                           = 11.
```

This is the code I have written. It returns in the tables `objcont` and `objhead` something but i don't know what to do with that output, since it looks like this:

```
&SO_KProObjectID=SOFFLOIO  E2ED5468C94941F198A300155D005612
```

and

```
&SO_FORMAT=BIN
```

respectively.

I've tried to do a `Where used` query on the Function module to see how it's used, but I didn't get the idea yet.

So does anyone know how to get the attachment as an in-memory file?

Comment: Have you tried to use `SO_ATTACHMENT_READ_API1`? This function module is released for customer use and comes with a documentation that also contains some sample code...

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use a program like [Mail Attachment Downloader](http://gearmage.com/maildownloader.html) to simplify processing rules and then feed the attachments into both a document management system and SAP.

We use the PRO Server version of Mail Attachment Downloader to do this and it works reasonably well.